# Express errorHandler()

Tags: node.js, express

have a simple app

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path=require('path');
var config = require('config');

var log = require('libs/log.js')(module);


var app = express();
app.set("port",config.port);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  log.info('Express server listening on port ' + config.port);
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    if(req.url=='/dn'){ 
        next(new Error('lol'));

    }else next();
});

app.use(function(err,req,res,next){
    if(app.get('env')=='development'){
        var errorHandler = app.use(express.errorHandler());
        errorHandler(err,req,res,next);
    }else{
        res.end(401);
    }
});
```

but have a page error like this 
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzrh2.png)

What i doing wrong ? in Express doc i cant find some examples like my.

UPD : use express 3.3.8 and node js  5.2.0 npm 3.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`express.errorHandler` was deprecated in Express 4, and there's now a separate package called [`errorhandler`](https://github.com/expressjs/errorhandler) that you should use instead. Also, `send.end()` cannot be used to just send a status code, you have to use [`sendStatus()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus) or [`status(...).end()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status).

So your code would become something like this:

```
var errorhandler = require('errorhandler')();

...

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    return errorhandler(err, req, res, next);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(401);
  }
});
```

For Express 3, the code would look like this:

```
var errorHandler = express.errorHandler();

...

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    return errorHandler(err, req, res, next);
  } else {
    res.send(401);
  }
});
```

Comment: i use express express@3.3.8 and node 5 , maybe in this problem ?

Comment: @izac if you can use Express@4 (i.e. if Express@3 isn't a specific requirement) I would suggest using it. If not, I can modify my answer to fit v3.

Comment: @robetklep ok , can u modify  please for Express 3